# Как исправить проблему пропавшего wifi-подключения?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

доброго дня, по непонятной причине в ubuntu 14.04 пропала возможность подключится к w-fi,
из панели где раньше выбирал wi-fi - опция просто исчезла. кто-то может подсказать чем проблема и возможно ли ее решить. до этого все отлично работало, убунту качала апдейты, возможно после этого пропала функция
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выхлопы `ifconfig -a` и `cat /etc/network/interfaces` в студию.

Comment: Это комп или ноут? Если ноут, то какой модели?